# Android: is it possible to only synchronize consumer but not producer?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, synchronization

Suppose in the following example, `deleteItems` (consumer) and `addItem` (producer) are used for multiple threads to delete and add items into the `map`.

```
class Test {
   public static SparseIntArray map = new SparseIntArray();
   
   // deleteItems is invoked every 10 seconds
   public static void deleteItems() {
       synchronized(Test.class) {
           // Iterate over the items in the map and delete some
       }
   }

   // addItem is invoked frequently
   public static void addItem(int key, int value) {
       // Add an item into the map
   }
}
```

I hope to achieve the following two goals:

(1) When `deleteItems` is invoked, any threads that are going to use `addItem` will be blocked.

(2) When `deleteItems` is NOT invoked, any threads can use `addItem` to put new items into the `map`. (I don't want to synchronize `addItem` because of efficiency issues)

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Is  `SparseIntArray` a sublcass of  a `Map` implementation?  Am I too assume that an instance of `ConcurrenthashMap` could not be used.

Comment: @WJS No, it is not a subclass of a Map.

Comment: What about ConcurrenthashMap?  You may want to edit your question and explain what you're trying to do rather than how to fix an intended solution. There may be alternate approaches to your ultimate task.

Answer (score 1):

So maybe (if I understood correctly) you need something like this:

You need a flag where you will make the threads wait until the deleting thread will end its job. The same goes for the "to delete" thread, it must wait for the adding threads to finish. So that's the idea :)

```
class Test {
   private SparseIntArray map = new SparseIntArray();
   private boolean isDeleting = false; 
   private int threadsAdding = 0;
   
   public synchronized void deleteItems() {
       while(threadsAdding != 0) { wait(); }

       isDeleting = true;
       ...
       exitDeleting();
   }

   public void addItem(int key, int value) throws InterruptedException {
       while (isDeleting) { wait(); }

       threadsAdding++;
       ...
       exitAdding();
   }

   private void exitDeleting() {
       isDeleting = false;
       notifyAll();
   }

   private void exitAdding() {
       threadsAdding--;
       notifyAll();
   }

}
```

If I missed something let me know so we can discuss it.

Hope it helped :) Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But I am concerning what if `isDeleting` is false when `addItem` begins so that the while loop in `addItem` will pass. Then another thread executes `deleteItems`. At this point, the map can be accessed by two threads, one is deleting items while another is adding items.

Comment: I understand your concern and maybe we should check before deletion. So this is a great corner case and we should check if we add things and wait. Let me write this one and lets talk about it again.

Comment: @RichardHu I am checking in if everything went well, otherwise, we must update my answer cause others will search too. Stackoverflow is all about documenting staff, cause other people maybe will have the same issue. thanks.